# I have installed the asyncpg package but I'm not able to import it in my code

Tags: pycharm, discord.py, asyncpg

My interface is Python 3.7 (venv) and I have installed the package into my interface as well as through terminal but for some reason the 'asyncpg' module is the only one not able to be imported. Any ideas?

I've tried restarting and reinstalling the package

> import asyncpg
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'asyncpg'

Comment: If you have a few python environments, make sure you import asyncpg from venv where it is installed. I have similar issue, but with docker container, where asyncpgsa is installed through `pip3 install asyncpgsa`, but application could not found the module. In my case it is really not clear why it could not import it.